# Why am I getting this error? CCSprite copyWithZone unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I'm having a tough time figuring out why I'm running into the error:

**CCSprite copyWithZone unrecognized selector sent to instance**

I would like to keep a reference to the rectangleSprite in the Rectangle object.  I synthesize it in the Rectangle.m file.  Am I doing something incorrectly with the way I'm trying to store the rectangleSprite in the Rectangle's rectangleSprite property?

### Rectangle.h

```
#import "CCNode.h"
#import "cocos2d.h"
#import "CCSprite.h"

@interface Rectangle : CCNode
{
    CCSprite *rectangleSprite;    
}

@property(nonatomic,readwrite,copy) CCSprite *rectangleSprite;

@end
```

### CocosScene.m

```
...
CCSprite *rectangleSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"rectangle.png"];
Rectangle *rectangle = [[Rectangle alloc] init];
rectangle.rectangleSprite = rectangleSprite;
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have defined the `rectangleSprite` property to be `copy`. This means that the `CCSprite` class must conform to the `NSCopying` protocol (which means it must implement the `copyWithZone:` method).

The error indicates that `CCSprite` does not implement `copyWithZone:`.

If you just wish to retain the value, get rid of `copy` in the property declaration. Use `strong` (or `retain` is using MRC) instead of `copy`.

You only use `copy` when you want to create a copy of the object when assigning it to the property. But this requires that the class support copying.